# htaccess 2 rules only 1st work

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z-0-9]+)$ linkovi.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-0-9]+)$ index.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How to enable both of these only 1st one work which ever it is.

Answer (score 1):

Both rules have the same *pattern* (`([a-z-0-9]+)`). Apache cannot guess what you want. You are better off doing something like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^linkovi/([a-z-0-9]+)$ linkovi.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-0-9]+)$ index.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Where the first rule is clearly different, matching requests to `linkovi/123`, for example.